# emacs doesnot work with xdg-open

Tags: 15.04, emacs, xdg-open

I use emacs 24.4.1 on ubuntu 15.04. Somehow xdg-open doesnot work if i run it from emacs. For example, if i run "xdg-open 1.pdf" or "gvfs-open 1.pdf" in eshell they do not work. At the same time, "evince 1.pdf" works perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The previous two answers didn't work for me:

- `(setq process-connection-type nil)` broke `org-plot/gnuplot`
- `setsid xdg-open ...` worked for a while, but then it stopped for some reason.

Now I use `setsid -w`, which supposedly makes `setsid` wait until the called program finishes.

If someone would need it, I use this with AUCTeX (and I found this question while trying to fix AUCTeX behavior on Arch linux), and my `TeX-command-list` is set to

```
(quote
 ( 
  ;; ...
  ("View" "setsid -w xdg-open %s.pdf" TeX-run-command t t :help "Run Text viewer")
  ;; ...
  )
```

It seems to work fine for now...

Comment: could you explain how to hook that into opening org mode links?

Answer (score 5):

Using `setsid xdg-open 1.pdf` works for me. The problem seems to be that `gvfs-open` and `xdg-open` return before their children are done working. Emacs might kill their controlling terminal when this happens, killing the children, and stopping `evince` from opening properly. `setsid` sets a new controlling terminal that emacs won't close.

Comment: To make it work I had to include `-w` (wait): `setsid -w xdg-open 1.pdf`

Comment: could you explain how to hook that into opening org mode links?

Answer (score 3):

This may be a problem with using ptys for subprocess communication. Try setting process-connection-type to nil to use pipes instead.

In your .emacs

```
;; Use pipes for subprocess communication
(setq process-connection-type nil)
```

I use the publishing functions from org mode and without this change, none of the generated files get opened via xdg-open, despite no error messages.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Is there some documentation containing some explanation for this?

Comment: This method does work, but might cause problems for other applications (for me it ruined calling gnuplot from org-mode), so it's not an optimal solution! I have Michael Hoffmans solution in my .emacs now (for the view command in Auctex). We'll see how it works.

Comment: To reproduce the error mentioned above: try running `org-plot/gnuplot` with the cursor/point on a table with and without `process-connection-type` set to `nil`, for more details see first subsection of [this page](http://orgmode.org/manual/Org_002dPlot.html).

Comment: also broke ripgrep search with ivy for me :/

Answer (score 2):

xdg-open work in sync mode: `(shell-command "xdg-open .")` ,
but not in async mode: `(async-shell-command "xdg-open .")` .

it seem like xdg-open spawn child process to open file then exit.
before child process open file, xdg-open exit, so shell exit, too.
shell exit kill all child process.

so just make shell life little more:
`(async-shell-command "xdg-open . ; sleep 1")`
(async-shell-command will append `&` after `sleep 1` ;
anyway, shell will still wait background process `&` finish.)

Comment: There's a relevant treemacs issue that this answer has helped me fix: https://github.com/Alexander-Miller/treemacs/issues/633

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by https://depp.brause.cc/dotemacs/#orgd97f08c here is a solution for `org-mode`:

```lisp
(setq org-file-apps '((remote . emacs)
                      (auto-mode . emacs)
                      (directory . emacs)
                      (system . "setsid -w xdg-open %s")
                      (t . system)))
```

This overrides the default associations and thus also prefers opening file formats such as PDF within Emacs if possible.
Alternatively, you can append to the existing list, as [mentioned on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3985552):

```lisp
(setq org-file-apps-gnu
      (append '((t . "setsid -w xdg-open %s")) org-file-apps-gnu))
```

The `t` means it will handle everything not explicitly handled by something else.
You can append to `org-file-apps` instead of `org-file-apps-gnu`, but since `xdg-open` is only commonly used on GNU systems, this should be ideal.

I used `(setq process-connection-type nil)` happily for a long time, but in the last days I found out that it broke integrations with `ripgrep` after hours of debugging. So I would heavily discourage that.